# summary on list with all the info you need using map

Tags: r

I have a list with 6 elements and need some summary statistics. Each element has a different number of observations but all have the same 9 variables. They were created using split, and thus each element is a different treatment. I want to create a table with: n, min, max, mean, SD, 5th quantile, and 95th quantile).

I am using the purrr package for the function `map()` which is similar to `lapply()` but its easier to debug.

From: `lapply(test,summary)`
I can get min, max, mean

n, and sd I was able to get with the following:

```
mdl_summary= map(test,col_summary, sd) %>%
    lapply(., setNames, nm=colnames  %>%
    map(.,t) %>%
    lapply(., function(x)  {
      row.names(x)=deparse(substitute(sd))
      return (x)
    })
```

with col_summary being another function code:

```
col_summary <- function(df, fun) {
  output <- vector("numeric", length(df))
  for (i in seq_along(df)) {
    output[[i]] <- fun(df[[i]])
  }
  output
}
```

But I cant get the quantiles...

I also tried to generalize `mdl_summary` into `mdl_summary_fun` but can't get the rowname to say the function it ran.

```
mdl_summary_fun= function (x,f)
  map(x,col_summary, f) %>%
  lapply(., setNames, nm=colnames(mdl$Statistics[2:10]))  %>%
  map(.,t) %>%
  lapply(., function(x)  {
    row.names(x)=deparse(substitute(f))
    return (x)
  })
```

Comment: List of elements? What type of elements? Vectors? Matrices? Dataframes? Please provide some data for a reproducible example. Use `dput()` on a few elements of list. With some data, this question would have been answered a few hours ago!

Answer (score 0):

I just had to modify the col_summary function I created to include extra arguments:

```
col_summary <- function(df, fun, ...) {
  output <- vector("numeric", length(df))
  for (i in seq_along(df)) {
    output[[i]] <- fun(df[[i]], ...)
  }
  output
}
```